# ESLint configuration woes

Tags: javascript, bash, sublimetext3, atom-editor, eslint

I am trying to use an eslint workflow.  I have installed Node via nvm and the nessary plugins globally:

```
├── babel-eslint@6.0.2
├── eslint@2.7.0
├── eslint-config-angular@0.5.0
├── eslint-config-semistandard@6.0.1
├── eslint-config-standard@5.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-angular@1.0.0
├── eslint-plugin-promise@1.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-standard@1.3.2
├── npm@3.8.3
├── standard@6.0.8
```

And locally in my project:

```
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "2.7.0",
"eslint-config-angular": "0.5.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "5.1.0",
"eslint-config-semistandard": "6.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "1.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "1.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "1.3.2"
},
```

And I have set up an `.eslintrc.json` file in my project root:

```
{
"env": {
  "browser": 1
},
"extends": "semistandard",
"plugins": [
    "standard","angular"
],
"globals": {
  "angular": 1,
  "$": 1,
  "angularDragula": 1
 }
}
```

The Atom ESlint and standard-formatter plugins find and respect my config file, but it not the command line or the Sublime Linter.  It does not read the config, so I get errors flagged:

[image]

Which make it obvious it's not reading the settings.  What am I doing wrong here?  As I said, it works in Atom but not command line or Sublime (which uses the command-line options).

Comment: Do you need to tell it where to find the config? Does it assume the local/project directory or assume a user-global config?

Comment: i tried both, as in `eslint -c ~/.eslintrc.json feedback-alerts.controller.js `

Comment: I'm not familiar with eslint but what about those errors indicates that it isn't reading your config? What do you get if you remove your config file and run the cli or use an empty config file with `-c`?

Comment: Same thing. I realize it's not reading the configuration, I just don't know why not.

Comment: Can you share the source code (possibly simplified) of the file that's giving you those errors?

Comment: Is `~` really your project root? And you say it isn't reading the config and maybe that's obvious to someone who knows what that config means but it isn't at all clear to me. That's why I was asking.

Comment: No problem  The file is a simple controller, and it passes eslint in Atom, which is reading the config file and picking up the globals in there for "angular" and "$". The file I am linting is http://f.cl.ly/items/37001W1X2H302b0O1G0m/feedback-alerts.controller.js

Comment: Based on the error messages, it looks like it's picking up your config just fine. If it weren't seeing the config, I'd expect to see a warning about `angular` being undefined. Instead, it's only warning about indent issues and `$scope` being undefined (was it not in the argument list originally?).

Comment: Try renaming your `.eslintrc.json` file to `.eslintrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against using a global installation of ESLint.  If you want to run it to lint the files in your project, you can use:

```
node_modules/.bin/eslint feedback-alerts.controller.js
```

Or, better yet, create an `npm script` for the task.  In your `package.json`, you can add:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint feedback-alerts.controller.js"
}
```

Furthermore, it looks like you are using a config file that is not in your project root (`~/.eslintrc.json` is in your user root, not project root).  ESLint will do its own config resolution, so you should not have to specify the path to the config file except in advanced cases.